# HIbernate Criteria Aliasing not joining

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, join, criteria-api

I have an entity Answer, that has a composite id AnswerId, which has both a Person entity and a Question entity, which have string ids of personId and questionId respectively. Also, the Question entity has a field questionText.

If I try something like:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(AnswerEntity.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("answerId.person.personId", personId));
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("answerId.question.questionId", questionId));
```

It works in that it filters the results based on the provided personId and questionId.

However, if I try:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(AnswerEntity.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("answerId.person.personId", personId)); 
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("answerId.question.questionText",questionText));
```

it fails. It says it can't find the questionText and the generated SQL shows why:

```
SELECT this_.PERSON_ID AS PERSON6_5_0_,
  this_.QUESTION_ID    AS QUESTION5_5_0_,
  this_.THEIR_ANSWER   AS THEIR3_5_0_,
FROM ANSWER this_
WHERE q1_.QUESTION_TEXT LIKE ?
AND this_.PERSON_ID=?
```

How do I a join between Answer and Question so that I can access questionText? I've tried adding an alias like

```
criteria.createAlias("answerId.question", "q"); 
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("q.questionText", "%" + text + "%"));
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Could anyone provide some assistance as to what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: The weird thing is, the Person entity also has a set of Answers, such that I can do a query on the Person and filter using a restriction like `"answers.answerId.question.questionText"` and it actually works. I'm not sure what is different.

Edit:  My entities (without getters/setters/equals/etc)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ANSWER")
public class AnswerEntity implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8254277382097937813L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private AnswerId answerId;

    @Column(name = "THEIR_ANSWER")
    private int theirAnswer;
}

@Embeddable
public class AnswerId implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7025913625856563058L;

    @OneToOne
    @Index(name = "ANSWER_QUESTION_ID_INDEX")
    @JoinColumn(name = "QUESTION_ID")
    @ForeignKey(name = "FKA1_QUESTION_ID")
    private QuestionEntity question;

    @ManyToOne
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    @Index(name = "ANSWER_PERSON_ID_INDEX")
    @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")
    @ForeignKey(name = "FKA2_PERSON_ID")
    private PersonEntity person;
}   

@Entity
@Table(name = "QUESTION")
public class QuestionEntity implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3083000088157555984L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "QUESTION_ID", nullable = false)
    private String questionId;

    @Index(name = "QUESTION_TEXT_INDEX")
    @Column(name = "QUESTION_TEXT", length = 4000, nullable = false)
    private String questionText;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your domain class definitions?

Comment: One could remove the PersonEntity as it fails without that restriction as well.

Comment: My guess is that somehow this composite key is making hibernate not realize it needs to join the Answer and Question tables.

Comment: Do you depend on this ER/domain model with composite primary keys? From my experience this can become rather messy and simple surrogate keys are much easier to handle.

Comment: I do depend on it as it makes a few things a little easier. I think I'm going to give up on doing this via criteria as doing it via HQL took all of two minutes and based on my google searching, Hibernate may very well not even support it.

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess, try:

```
criteria.createAlias("question.questionText", "qText"); 
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("answerId.qText", "%" + text + "%"));
```

Edit: the reasoning behind this (to make the wild guess an educated guess ;) is that you don't need an alias or `SubCriteria` to navigate to embedded properties like `myEembedded.myProperty`. You need an alias or a `SubCriteria` however to navigate to properties of a related entity like `myRelatedEntity.myProperty`.

Comment: Sadly, this did not work, but it was something I hadn't tried. I think I'm just going to use HQL.